# cakephp dynamic select box issue

Tags: cakephp

Hello helper i am begginer in cake i have a issue i have a select box which is like this.

```
<select name="services" id="services" class="form-control">
<option value="0">Room PG Rent</option>
<option value="1">Placement</option>
<option value="2">Restaurant</option>
<option value="3">Movers and Packers</option>
</select>
```

but i need that value should be same like option. like option value Room PG Rent, Placement... not like 0 1 ... 
here is my controller

```
$this->loadModel("Services");
$agetservices = $this->Services->getservices();
$this->set(compact('agetservices'));
for($i=0;$i<count($agetservices);$i++)
{
$agetservices[$i]=$agetservices[$i]['Services']['name'];
}
$this->set('agetservices', $agetservices);
```

here is my view.

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('cities', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'name' => 'cities',
        'id'=>'cities',
        'label' => 'City <span class="required small">(Required)</span>',
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'placeholder'=>'Search For Anything Anywhere in Jaipur',
        'options' => $agetservices,
        'empty'   => false
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this the $cities array must be like this:

```
array(
    'Room PG Rent' => 'Room PG Rent',
    'Placement' => 'Placement',
    'Movers and Packers' => 'Movers and Packers'
)
```

To convert the $cities array to this format do:

```
$cities = array_combine($cities, $cities);
```